# send a javascript variable to a php script

Tags: javascript, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I am using google's reverse geocoding to find the current city of a user and i using javascript to do this.
After having the name ,I want to send this variable to a php file so that i can use the country or city to do other things.Here is what i have tried.

```
function displayLocation(latitude,longitude){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var method = 'GET';
    var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+latitude+','+longitude+'&sensor=true';
    var async = true;

    request.open(method, url, async);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var address = data.results[0];
        var city_name = address.formatted_address;
       // var count = results[0].address_components[1];
        var x = document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = city_name;
        alert('you are accessing us from : '+ city_name);
        $.ajax({
           url:"yourphp.php",
           type:"POST",
           async:false,
           data:{quantity:city_name}
        }).done(function(d){
           returnvariable =d;
        });

        }
    };
    request.send();
  };


  var successCallback = function(position){
    var x = position.coords.latitude;
    var y = position.coords.longitude;
    displayLocation(x,y);
  };
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback,errorCallback,options);
```

I am getting the location correctly but sending it to my php file is difficult.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the way you're sending it to the PHP file. Maybe the problem is in the PHP script. Is it getting the city name from `$_POST['quantity']`?

Comment: if i do echo $_POST['quantity']; on the php file(yourphp.php) i dont see anything

Comment: Where are you looking for it? Your `.done()` function doesn't display the response anywhere.

Comment: BTW, you should try to avoid using `async: false`, it's deprecated.